# Using Stripe.JS React in chrome extension failure

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension, stripe-payments, babeljs

I'm trying to use Stripejs for react for make payments in content script in Chrome Extension. 
I'm still getting error : Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://js.stripe.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://www.*****.com').
Im my main content script component i have:

```
let stripePromise; 
...
componentDidMount() {
    stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_CGTRvaOpa53ZQlUXYikMtf0r001D8XRnHQ');
  }
...

<Col>
 <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
  <CheckoutForm/>
 </Elements>
</Col>
```

And in CheckoutForm i have:

```
export const CheckoutForm = () => {
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!stripe || !elements) {
            return;
        }

        const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);

        const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: 'card',
            card: cardElement,
        });

        if (error) {
            console.log('[error]', error);
        } else {
            console.log('[PaymentMethod]', paymentMethod);
        }
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <CardElement />
            <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe}>
                Pay
      </button>
        </form>
    );
};
```

I have empty div with card:

[image]

And in console: 
[image]

The extension is implemented by webpack, babel and gulp tasks in latest versions.

I'm added:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "https://js.stripe.com/v3/";
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

In webpack index.js file of this component but this didn't help.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Stripe Elements works in a Chrome Extension; you'll need to send the user to an HTTPS payment page for this.

Comment: Have you any other solutions to make payments in chrome extension in content script or in popup?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no.

Comment: Try to create a page like this:
chrome-extension://hjdyfdnfleobejgjajmgkfahnafphfooa/checkout/index.html